# remaining time in the progress dialog

Tags: user-interface, time

In a GUI application I would like to show a progess dialog displaying how much time left for the task to accomplish, how may I get the remaining time before the task ends and count it down please? thanks

Comment: Is this GUI application something you are working on--in other words: you have the source code for?  What programming language are you using?  You are rather vague about the details.

Comment: @Russ, yes, I got the source code for it

Answer (score 1):

How to get the remaining time is something no-one but your application (or you) can know.

Comment: Probably you have to estimate from information you have: I would guess that e. g. Windows Explorer just projects the expected remaining duration somehow from the number of files and number of bytes to copy, and the number of files and number of bytes already copied and the duration it has taken so far.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the code for this GUI application, to determine remaining time you simply need to know the total time a task takes and subtract the amount of time that passed since the start of the task.